# How could I plot 2 different values (X) in one column in the dataset, python

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib, plot

I want to plot The gender in one scatter plot
x=[0,1] .. 0 refers to male and 1 refers to female
y= cholesterol , here is my code.. the problem I don't want any value in x-axis but male and female

```
plt.scatter(heart_data["Sex"],heart_data["Cholesterol"] ,s=20,c='pink')
plt.xlabel("Sex")
plt.ylabel("Cholesterol")
```

Comment: You are describing one of the typical use cases for seaborn:  `sns.scatter(data=heart_data, x='"sex", y="Cholesterol")`.  Or `sns.swarmplot(data=heart_data, x='"sex", y="Cholesterol")`.